# Copy column data from one table to another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases, one which is **old** and one which is **new**. I need to copy one particular column from the old to the new. Structure-wise they are both totally identical, although the new table is significantly larger than the old, and the only way i can connect these two tables together by a foreignkey is the `uni_id`, which is just a normal integerfield, but its unique.

So this is basically the structure of the table:

```
|    id    |    name    |    name_pseudo    |    uni_id    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to compare each row of `new_db.mytable` with `old_db.mytable` by `uni_id` and insert `old_db.mytable.name_pseudo` into `new_db.mytable.name_pseudo`.

Can such expression in pure MySQL be constructed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MySQL manual on [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables. However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT with a multiple-table UPDATE. The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the join. Its syntax is described in Section 13.2.9.2, “JOIN Syntax”. Here is an example:

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price
    WHERE items.id=month.id;
```

Which in your case should read like:

```
UPDATE newdb.mytable AS new, old_db.mytable AS old
    SET new.name_pseudo=old.name_pseudo
    WHERE old.uni_id=new.uni_id;
```

Comment: Strange, `only 1 row affected`.